# How to change indentation in text-mode for emacs

Tags: emacs, indentation

I'm in text mode and want my tab key to indent a line to two spaces.

The file looks like this:

```
Line one

Line two
```

The cursor is situated before the 'L' : "Line two", and I hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> and it gets indented 6 spaces as opposed to the desired 2 spaces.

Actions I've tried:

1. I've tried updating the variable: `tab-stop-list`

   ```lisp
   (setq tab-stop-list '(2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16))
   ```
2. I've tried adding a `text-mode-hook`

   ```lisp
   (add-hook 'text-mode-hook
     '(lambda ()
       (setq tab-width 2)))
   ```

Answer (score 10):

Add this to your .emacs :

```lisp
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook
          '(lambda ()
             (setq indent-tabs-mode nil)
             (setq tab-width 2)
             (setq indent-line-function (quote insert-tab))))
```

See [Emacs Indentation Tutorial](http://www.xemacs.org/Links/tutorials_1.html).

Answer (score 2):

The default for  in text-mode will indent to the first non-whitespace character in the line above it.

From the key binding documentation in text mode

> TAB (translated from ) runs the command indent-for-tab-command,
>   which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `indent.el'.
>
> It is bound to TAB.
>
> (indent-for-tab-command &optional ARG)
>
> Indent line or region in proper way for current major mode or insert a tab.
>   Depending on `tab-always-indent', either insert a tab or indent.
>
> In most major modes, if point was in the current line's indentation,
>   it is moved to the first non-whitespace character after indenting;
>   otherwise it stays at the same position in the text....

Luckily, this can be changed.  Adding the following to your text-mode-hook should do what you need:

```lisp
(setq tab-width 2)
(setq indent-line-function (quote insert-tab))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting

```lisp
(setq standard-indent 2)
```

In your `.emacs`