# How do I override indent function for emacs plain-text major mode?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I tried following in the scratch buffer:

```
(defun r-text-indent ()
  (interactive)
  (indent-line-to 4)) ;; 4 is just for example

(setq indent-line-function 'r-text-indent)
```

Evaluating those made scratch buffer indent everything 4 spaces. But all other buffers were unaffected.

How do I make this function to be used in all my plain-text buffers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a hook such that the variable is set for text-mode:

```lisp
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
         (setq indent-line-function 'r-text-indent)))
```

See also http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ModeHooks and [How to change indentation in text-mode for emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976240/how-to-change-indentation-in-text-mode-for-emacs).